# 自プログラムが使用するBSDライセンスのOSSが、GPLライセンスのOSSを使っている場合の、伝播性、公開義務について

Tags: ライセンス, gpl, oss

まず、今の状況を説明します。
GPLのソフトウェアを動的リンクしたOSSが3条項BSDライセンスで公開されています。
具体的には、MRPT(https://www.mrpt.org/)というライブラリです。
私が作成するプログラムにて、MRPTを動的リンクして使っています。

質問1. MRPTのライセンスについて、GPLの伝播の規定により、GPLをリンクした場合は、GPLで公開しなければいけないのではないでしょうか。「動的リンクなら伝播しない」という見解があるのは認識しています。
MRPTは、この見解のもと、GPLではないライセンスを適用しているのでしょうか。
"GPL互換ライセンス"ということが関係しているのであれば、その辺りの説明も含め、教えて頂きたいです。

質問2. 自分の作成するプログラムは、GPLのライブラリを直接使っていませんが、それでも、MRPT越しにGPLを使っているので、GPLの条項の適用範囲にはなるでしょうか。

質問3. 自分の作成するプログラムに対して、公式サイトのQA通り適用されるというスタンスをとるのであれば、GPLにして公開する必要があるのでしょうか。

質問4. 自分の作成するプログラムに対して、「動的リンクなら伝播しない」という見解を適用するのならば、GPLを適用しないことはもちろん、ソース公開義務も発生しないのでしょうか。

Comment: GPLはどのライブラリの話なのかを明示していただけないでしようか？

Comment: Qt, Libav, SuiteSparse(CHOLMOD), E2fsprogs, fontconfig　などで、左記は一部であり、他にもありそうです。

Comment: MySQL(client), freeglut といったあたりも、使ってます。

Comment: [copyright](https://github.com/MRPT/mrpt/blob/master/packaging/debian/copyright)を見る限り、GPLは一つもなくてLGPLしかないようですが。

Comment: このcopyrightは、MRPT内のファイルについてで、リンクしてるパッケージについてではないですよね。私が挙げたのは、MRPTとは別のパッケージなので、ここには記載ありません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

私の解釈です。他の回答者の回答などと比較の上、判断してください。

> 質問1. MRPTのライセンスについて、GPLの伝播の規定により、GPLをリンクした場合は、GPLで公開しなければいけないのではないでしょうか。「動的リンクなら伝播しない」という見解があるのは認識しています。
> MRPTは、この見解のもと、GPLではないライセンスを適用しているのでしょうか。
> "GPL互換ライセンス"ということが関係しているのであれば、その辺りの説明も含め、教えて頂きたいです。

「静的・動的問わず」と [GNU が公式に明言](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.ja.html#GPLStaticVsDynamic)しているので、それはないでしょうね。

> (GPLの)及ぶ作品に対し、静的 vs 動的にリンクされたモジュールについて、GPLには異なる要求がありますか? (#GPLStaticVsDynamic)
> いいえ。GPLの及ぶ作品に静的もしくは動的にほかのモジュールとリンクすることは、GPLの及ぶ作品をもとにして結合著作物を作成することです。ですから、全体としての結合には、GNU一般公衆ライセンスの条項が及びます。

静的・動的で違いが生ずるのは [LGPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.ja.html#LGPLStaticVsDynamic) のはずです。

また、MRPT の作者がそのような見解の下に非 GPL ライセンスを適用しているわけではないでしょう。修正 BSD は GPL 互換ライセンスですから、MRPT の作者が、自分たちの著作権の及ぶ範囲に対して、修正 BSD を採用することができます。

> 質問2. 自分の作成するプログラムは、GPLのライブラリを直接使っていませんが、それでも、MRPT越しにGPLを使っているので、GPLの条項の適用範囲にはなるでしょうか。

なります。GPL の趣旨からして、「間接利用ならば GPL によるフリープログラムに対する保護をスルーして、プロプラエリーな著作物を構築してフリープログラムの発展を阻害できる」ということでは、お話にならないからです。

> 質問3. 自分の作成するプログラムに対して、公式サイトのQA通り適用されるというスタンスをとるのであれば、GPLにして公開する必要があるのでしょうか。

GPL そのものにする必要はありませんが、修正 BSD 等の**いずれかの互換ライセンスにして公開する**必要はあるでしょう。

> 質問4. 自分の作成するプログラムに対して、「動的リンクなら伝播しない」という見解を適用するのならば、GPLを適用しないことはもちろん、ソース公開義務も発生しないのでしょうか。

そういうことになるのなら、やはり、GPL の趣旨が骨抜きになるわけで、だから GPL では禁じているのではないかと思います。

要するに、まず基本的な第一前提として **公開（オープンソース）** があるわけです。で、第二に、公開にあたって、GPL そのものを適用せずとも、互換ライセンスを適用することも選べますよ、という話。

反対に、非公開（プロプラエタリー）にするため、GPL から、間接的動的リンクなら云々と、ok な理由を引っ張り出そうとするのは無理があると思います。それはあくまでも GPL に対立する立場からの見解です。グレーゾーンを承知でリスクを取るということになると思います。少なくともオープンソースにしている MRPT の作者は、そういうグレーゾーン的理由を盾に修正 BSD にしているわけではないであろうことは説明した通りです。

Comment: おそらくこうだろう、と考えていた意見と一致しました。

> 修正 BSD は GPL 互換ライセンスですから、MRPT の作者が、自分たちの著作権の及ぶ範囲に対して、修正 BSD を採用することができます。

このようにいえる根拠は、何かありますでしょうか？そもそもライセンスとは、そういうものである、ということでしょうか。

Comment: > なります。GPL の趣旨からして、「間接利用ならば GPL によるフリープログラムに対する保護をスルーして、プロプラエリーな著作物を構築してフリープログラムの発展を阻害できる」ということでは、お話にならないからです。

=> GPLの文面でいうと、MRPTの.soファイルとGPLのライブラリが「結合著作物」となり、結合著作物に対してGPLが適用されるから、というところからこうなるのでは、と考えていましたが、認識あっていますでしょうか。

Comment: > GPL そのものにする必要はありませんが、修正 BSD 等のいずれかの互換ライセンスにして公開する必要はあるでしょう。
=> 上記に関しては、おそらく、事例からもそうなんだと思っていますが、そうした時に１点疑問になるのが「GPLの伝播性」に関してで、修正BSDでリリースできるのであれば、伝播はしないので、伝播性はそれほどないのではないかと思いましたが、ここはやはり、静的リンクか動的リンクか、というが、判断材料になるのでしょうか。(リンクしていなくても、共有メモリなどで、データ結合があれば伝播する、という考えもあるというのもよくみますが。)

Comment: @YossyTKB (1) GNU が GPL 互換であるとリストアップして認めているから、そうでしょうということです。(2) 結合著作物になる「から」ではなく、理由はフリーソフトの保護です。結合著作物は理由ではなく、そこの範囲に及ばせるものとするよ、というライセンスの宣言です。意図的に GPL 伝播を定義しているものです。(3) 間接利用であって、間に互換ライセンスが挟まっていても、GPL ソフトを利用することになる限り、いわゆる GPL 汚染が及びます。この場合、間の互換ライセンスのみに基くようにして、GPL から自由になるためには、間のソフトのみを利用し、間のソフトが利用している GPL ライセンスのライブラリー等（静的・動的問わず）を自力で別のものに置き換えるなどして対応するしかないと思います。間の互換ライセンスソフトもオープンソースなわけですから、そのライセンスに基いて、自力でどうにかする余地は残されているわけです。